# "Text file busy" error on multithreading python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a python script which downloads shell scripts from amazon S3 server and then executes them (each script is about 3GB in size). The function that downloads and executes the file looks like this:

```
import boto3

def parse_object_key(key):
    key_parts = key.split(':::')
    return key_parts[1]

def process_file(file):
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    node = parse_object_key(file)
    file_path = "/tmp/" + node + "/tmp.sh"
    os.makedirs(file_path)
    client.download_file('category', file, file_path)
    os.chmod(file_path, stat.S_IXUSR)
    os.system(file_path)
```

The node is unique for each file.

I created a for loop to execute this:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('category')
for object in bucket.objects.page_size(count=50):
    process_file(object.key, client)
```

This works perfectly, but when I try to create a separate thread for each file, I get error:

```
sh: 1: /path/to/file: Text file busy
```

The script with threading looks like:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('category')
threads = []
for object in bucket.objects.page_size(count=50):
    t = threading.Thread(target=process_file, args=(object.key, client))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Out of all the threads, exactly one thread succeed and all other fail on "Text file busy error". Can someone help me figure out what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: What is `parse_file`?

Comment: And, for that matter, what is `download`?

Comment: It parses the file_name to get url and node, they are encoded in the file_name itself. Download just makes an http request to remote url to download the file and saves it at fie_path

Comment: We need to see the source, your question is incomplete without it.

Comment: Added the detailed code with exact source of downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Boto3 is not thread-safe so you cannot re-use your S3 connection for each download. See [here](http://ls.pwd.io/2013/06/parallel-s3-uploads-using-boto-and-threads-in-python/) for details of a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I made the changes to create client in every thread but I am still getting the same issue. It looks like the files get downloaded correctly, but the execution step fails with "Text file busy" error. Also, exactly one thread succeeds and all other fail.

Comment: Try using `subprocess` instead of `os.system` - https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system